# How to upscale the interface of IntelliJ IDEA/WebStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, high-dpi, webstorm

I may change the font size in work area using ctrl+mouse wheel. Can i also change the program interface size? (I use high ppi monitor)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can change UI font size in `File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance`, `Override default fonts`

Update: starting with version 2017.2 IDEA/WebStorm support per-display-DPI mode on Windows, but it doesn't work always.
If you experience problems with scaling, try setting UI font to default in `Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance` – uncheck `Override default font`, if it’s checked.
If it doesn’t help, please add `-Dsun.java2d.uiScale.enabled=false` to VM options using menu `Help | Edit custom VM options`.

Comment: Thanks. How about icon sizes?

Comment: they can't be scaled manually

Comment: There is no an option to work in HiPpi mode like in adobe products? May be, it is possible to change ppi of icons and other graphical elements of interface using changed IDEA's files?

Comment: Normally it is scaled by default to meet monitor DPI. But there might be problems when switching between monitors - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141456

Comment: Just wanted to add that Intellij Idea/PhpStorm/whatever seems to only work when your display settings are scaled up to 200%, beyond that it just sort of turns off. I used three monitors, and if any have their scaling above 200% the font is too small to read.

Comment: @slim yes, the IDE UI is currently limited to 2x scale. Please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171404 for updates

Comment: 300% actually works for some reason.

Comment: lol... ok, hopefully this is my last comment to this question. IJ will scale the UI properly *IF* the scaling factor is a multiple of 100 percent. So.. 100%, 200%, and even 300% all work, but, 150%, 250%, etc do not. @lena can you add this to your bug report?

Comment: it might have improved https://stackoverflow.com/a/54774584/260242